# Error when calling arrayVector() in a SQL query

Tags: sql, group-by, dolphindb

In DolphinDB, I wrote the following query where the function `arrayVector` is used to store the “lastprice“ column as an array vector:

```
bars=select first(sx), last(sx), first(sx)-last(sx)+1 as window, last(lastprice) as o, max(lastprice) as h, min(lastprice) as l, first(lastprice) as c,  arrayVector([size(lastprice)], lastprice) as lastprice_arr from ticks group by bar(sx_desc,barsize,closed='right')
```

An error was raised indicating that I should use the function `toArray` instead. So I changed the query to:

```
bars=select first(sx), last(sx), first(sx)-last(sx)+1 as window, last(lastprice) as o, max(lastprice) as h, min(lastprice) as l, first(lastprice) as c,  toArray(lastprice) as lastprice_arr from ticks group by bar(sx_desc,barsize,closed='right')
```

This query was successfully executed. But I want to know why the first query was wrong. Is it because `arrayVector` is not allowed in a “select“ clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got an error because the SQL query contains a “group by“ clause and it can only be used in conjunction with an aggregate function.

DolphinDB provides the toArray function to be used in conjunction with the `group by` clause in a SQL query. `toArray` stores the values in each group as a row of an array vector, so the values of each group can be presented in one row.